# On resize, loading an image using the asset function in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a header with an image loaded with the `asset` laravel function :

```
<img class="logo" src="{{ asset('images/logo-long.gif') }}" id="logo-navbar"></img>
```

And in my JS script, i want it to check whenever the size of the window is below 700px, the `src` atribute of the `img` tag change

So i implemented this :

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    width = $(window).width();
    if(width <= 700){
        $('#logo-navbar').attr('src', '??');
    }else{
        $('#logo-navbar').attr('src', '??');
    }
});
```

but i don't know how can i tell my script to generate a path like the asset function of laravel..

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can also simply use the HTML `<picture>` tag to provide different pictures at a given viewport and without Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using JS to change image URL you should't use PHP at all. It's bad practice. Just create image URL manually:

```
var imageBig = '/images/logo-long.gif';
var imageSmall = '/images/logo-sm.gif';
```

Comment: If you have just two logos use absolute path to the image instead of relative one (`/images/logo.gif` instead of `images/logo.gif`). This path will work on all pages. http://www.natashabanegas.com/use-absolute-paths-instead-of-relative-to-link-to-css-js-and-media-files/

Comment: Oh ! ok ! Thank you sir !

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not the best approach to do this, but you can do something like:

JavaScript:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    width = $(window).width();
    if(width <= 700){
        $('#logo-navbar').attr('src', '/getAsset/images/logo-long.gif');
    }else{
        $('#logo-navbar').attr('src', '/getAsset/images/logo-long.gif');
    }
});
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get("/getAsset/{any}", function ($asset) {
      return redirect(asset($asset));
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this one of two ways.

I either have some global container

```
var myApp = {};
```

where I then can assign various values via a view, I assign the value inline

```
myApp.url = {{ asset('/') }}
```

or, if the javascript is in the view

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var assetUrl = "{{ asset('/') }}";
    width = $(window).width();
    if(width <= 700){
        $('#logo-navbar').attr('src', assetURL +'/images/logo-long.gif');
    }else{
        $('#logo-navbar').attr('src', assetURL + '/images/logo-long.gif');
    }
});
```

Should note that I generally do this with url(), rather than asset() - I'm not sure if it will work the same exact same way.